# Add action for button in Today extension (widget) in iOS 8?

Tags: widget, ios8, ios-app-extension

I have a button in Widget iOS8. How can I get event when button on click?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After you setup the button, just add a target to the button as you would in your app. For example in viewDidLoad.

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```